# How to open VS.NET console window?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a few Console.Writeline()'s in my code. The Output window is open but I don't see any of my output appearing there.

Does this appear in a different window?

Comment: It might, there is an option to send it to the Immediate window instead.  And another option to use the Visual Studio Hosting process, required to make this work.  Or it is the wrong kind of project.  Entirely too much guessing and the question title makes no sense at all.  I'll vote for #2, Project > Properties > Debug tab.

Answer (score 0):

You should find the the console output in the "Immediate Window".

Comment: Please show how one can get to the "Immediate Window" or point to a website that explains it.

Comment: I found the immediate window Debug --> Windows --> Immediate but I don't see Console output going to it.